# Deriving 'y' matrix and sampling rate as the parameters of audiowrite function i.e audiowrite(filename,y,Fs)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am a bit lost in understanding how audiowrite function derives 'y', and 'Fs', the last two parameters of the function. I looked at some of the examples provided by Matlab, and they seem to work fine. The first set of codes is an example by Matlab which returns 'y' and 'Fs' value.

`load handel.mat
 filename = 'handel.wav';
 audiowrite(filename,y,Fs);`

Now, I have written a similar set of codes to work with a .csv file. Knowing the input argument for load function can only be in .mat format, I have written some codes in the following format.

```
csvread('bgst.csv');
save bgst.mat
load bgst.mat;
filename = 'bgst.wav';
audiowrite(filename,y,Fs);
```

But, in this case I am getting the error message: Undefined function or variable 'y'(or, Fs if I have defined y in the line w/ csvread function). So, why audiowrite is not creating 'y', and 'Fs' by itself as in the previous case. BTW, my .csv file is 999998x4 double. And, any more information to help me out, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
load handel.mat
```

You are [loading a MAT-file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) containing variables into the workspace. This is what initializes `y` and `Fs`, which are used as input arguments to [`audiowrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html). You can see this using the [`whos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) function to see the variables being created:

```
>> clear all        % Removes all current variables
>> load handel.mat
>> whos
  Name          Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  Fs            1x1                  8  double              
  y         73113x1             584904  double
```

The variable `y` contains the matrix of audio data with sampling rate `Fs`. You have to create these yourself for your data and pass them to `audiowrite`.

Comment: Thanks. I know the Fs is the sampling rate. I am wondering in the case when Matlab loads a file, what factors determine the Fs. In other words, how am I going to define Fs?

Comment: @Ialam: MATLAB can't automatically determine an `Fs` for you. You have to specify it. Where did you get your data in `'bgst.csv'`? If you got it from a particular device, you should know the frequency it was sampled at.

Comment: Oh, Fs is the frequency the data was sampled at by ADC! Thank you very much.